# Using Buffer tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, buffer

I am using the Buffer tool in QGIS to put a 30 Meter buffer around a number of points. When I do this the buffer ends up taking over the entire map. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPTh9.png)

[image: initial points]

[image: buffer tool]

[image: Finished buffer 1]

[image: Finished buffer 2]

Comment: Check the coordinate system of your source data that it is in a UTM or other system defined in METRES - otherwise, you're likely in WGS84, where '30' decimal degrees is MASSIVE...

Comment: I would guess that your data are in EPSG:4326 and the buffer of 30 units is not 30 meters but 30 degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was:

> Right-Click on the Layer > Save As > Change the CRS to (NC State Plane) > New Project > Project > Project Properties > On the Fly > NC State Plane > Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Buffer > Unit = 98.424 (30 * 3.2808)

Answer (score 2):

you could also do the conversion from degrees to meters which changes depending on the coordenates , on my case NE of Spain 0.000004°=0.9 mts
approx. There are on line calculators like http://msi.nga.mil/MSISiteContent/StaticFiles/Calculators/degree.html